# TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable using WithColumn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like append a new column on dataframe "df" from function `get_distance`:

```py
def get_distance(x, y):
    dfDistPerc = hiveContext.sql("select column3 as column3, \
                                  from tab \
                                  where column1 = '" + x + "' \
                                  and column2 = " + y + " \
                                  limit 1")

    result = dfDistPerc.select("column3").take(1)
    return result

df = df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    lit(get_distance(df["column1"], df["column2"]))
)
```

But, I get this:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I think it happens because x and y are `Column` objects and I need to be converted to `String` to use in my query. Am I right? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spark should know the function that you are using is not ordinary function but the UDF.

So, there are 2 ways by which we can use the UDF on dataframes.

**Method-1: With @udf annotation**

```
@udf
def get_distance(x, y):
    dfDistPerc = hiveContext.sql("select column3 as column3, \
                                  from tab \
                                  where column1 = '" + x + "' \
                                  and column2 = " + y + " \
                                  limit 1")

    result = dfDistPerc.select("column3").take(1)
    return result

df = df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    lit(get_distance(df["column1"], df["column2"]))
)
```

**Method-2: Regestering udf with pyspark.sql.functions.udf**

```
def get_distance(x, y):
    dfDistPerc = hiveContext.sql("select column3 as column3, \
                                  from tab \
                                  where column1 = '" + x + "' \
                                  and column2 = " + y + " \
                                  limit 1")

    result = dfDistPerc.select("column3").take(1)
    return result

calculate_distance_udf = udf(get_distance, IntegerType())

df = df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    lit(calculate_distance_udf(df["column1"], df["column2"]))
)
```

Answer (score 6):

- You cannot use Python function on a `Column` objects directly, unless it is intended to operate on `Column` objects / expressions. You need `udf` for that:

  ```
  @udf
  def get_distance(x, y):
      ...
  ```
- But you cannot use `SQLContext` in udf (or mapper in general).
- Just `join`:

  ```
  tab = hiveContext.table("tab").groupBy("column1", "column2").agg(first("column3"))
  df.join(tab, ["column1", "column2"])
  ```