# How to use date_add with two columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with some columns:

```
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
|country_name| ID_user|birth_date|      psdt|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
|      Россия|16460783|       486|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16467391|      4669|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16467889|      6861|1970-01-01|
|   Казахстан|16468013|      5360|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16471027|      6311|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16474162|      5567|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16476386|      4351|1970-01-01|
|      Россия|16481067|      3831|1970-01-01|
|   Казахстан|16485965|     -2369|1970-01-01|
|    Германия|16486027|      5864|1970-01-01|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I need to add "psdt" with "birth_date". I wrote this code, but (sf.date_add) doesn't work:

```
resultbirthDF =(
        resultDF
        .select(sf.col("country_name"),
                sf.col("ID_user"),
                sf.col("birth_date"),
                sf.lit(past_datetr).alias("psdt")
               )
        .withColumn("birth_datetrue",sf.date_add(sf.to_date(sf.col("psdt")),sf.col("birth_date")))
    ).show(10)

'Column' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volumes/disk1/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1573843665329_0786/container_e05_1573843665329_0786_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1006, in date_add
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.date_add(_to_java_column(start), days))
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting and what have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable using WithColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305443/typeerror-column-object-is-not-callable-using-withcolumn)

Comment: What is `sf`? dataframe? then why are you calling `sf.date_add` and `sf.to_date`?

Comment: @Lamanus `sf` is `pyspark.sql.functions`

Comment: @vs97 This is not at all a duplicate of the mentioned question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Pyspark Documentation

> pyspark.sql.functions.date_add(start, days)
>
> ```
> Returns the date that is days days after start
>
> >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['dt'])
> >>> df.select(date_add(df.dt, 1).alias('next_date')).collect()
> [Row(next_date=datetime.date(2015, 4, 9))]
> ```

Try changing your code to `sf.date_add(sf.to_date(sf.col("psdt")), 10)` and see if 10 days get added. `date_add` expects the first argument to be a column and the second argument to be an integer (*for the number of days you want to add to the column*).

**You can do exactly what you want to do without a UDF, but using a SQL expression** as follows:

```
df.withColumn("birth_datetrue", expr("date_add(psdt, birth_date)"))
```

**Sample output**:

```
df.withColumn("new_dt", F.expr("date_add(dt, add)")).show()

+----------+---+----------+
|        dt|add|    new_dt|
+----------+---+----------+
|2015-04-08|  1|2015-04-09|
|2015-04-09|  2|2015-04-11|
|2015-04-10|  3|2015-04-13|
+----------+---+----------+
```

Comment: you solution of using `expr` works for me. My concern is that in the latest official documentation it says that `date_add` function accepts also Column type as second parameter : (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_add.html)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spark Python API 3.3.0 you can use date_add with Column types as  the second parameter:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#date_add

So your original code in the question with not raise any error.