# Pyspark Data Frame: Access to a Column (TypeError: Column is not iterable)

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am struggling with a PySpark code, in particular, I'd like to call a function on an object `col` which is not iterable.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lower, regexp_replace, split
from googletrans import Translator

def clean_text(c):
  c = lower(c)
  c = regexp_replace(c, r"^rt ", "")
  c = regexp_replace(c, r"(https?\://)\S+", "")
  c = regexp_replace(c, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "") #removePunctuation 
  c = regexp_replace(c, r"\n", " ")
  c = regexp_replace(c, r"   ", " ")
  c = regexp_replace(c, r"  ", " ")  
#   c = translator.translate(c, dest='en', src='auto')
  return c

clean_text_df = uncleanedText.select(clean_text(col("unCleanedCol")).alias("sentence"))
clean_text_df.printSchema()
clean_text_df.show(10)
```

As soon as I run the code within `c = translator.translate(c, dest='en', src='auto')` the error shown from Spark is `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

What I would like to do is a translation word by word:

From:

```
+--------------------+
|            sentence|
+--------------------+
|ciao team there a...|
|dear itteam i urg...|
|buongiorno segnal...|
|hi team regarding...|
|hello please add ...|
|ciao vorrei effet...|
|buongiorno ho vis...|
+--------------------+
```

To:

```
+--------------------+
|            sentence|
+--------------------+
|hello team there ...|
|dear itteam i urg...|
|goodmorning segna...|
|hi team regarding...|
|hello please add ...|
|hello would effet...|
|goodmorning I see...|
+--------------------+
```

The schema of the `DataFrame` is:

```
root
 |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: You'll have to define a  `udf` to use `Translator.translate`. The other function calls are all built-in pyspark functions.

Comment: I couldn't find a good duplicate target for this question, surprisingly. The closest I found was: [TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable using WithColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305443/typeerror-column-object-is-not-callable-using-withcolumn). If anyone finds a better one, ping me.

Answer (score 3):

PySpark is just the Python API written to support Apache Spark. If you want to use custom python functions, you will have to define a user defined function ([`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf)).

Keep your `clean_text()` function as is (with the `translate` line commented out) and try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.Types import StringType

def translate(c):
  return translator.translate(c, dest='en', src='auto')

translateUDF = udf(translate, StringType())

clean_text_df = uncleanedText.select(
  translateUDF(clean_text(col("unCleanedCol"))).alias("sentence")
)
```

The other functions in your original `clean_text` ([`lower`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lower) and [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace)) are built-in spark functions and operate on a[`pyspark.sql.Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column).

Be aware that using this `udf` will bring a performance hit. See: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)