# select customer buy items in 2 lists in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to filter the customer who bought both items in the `list_1` and `list_2`

```
list_1 = [A, B, C, D]

list_2 = [E, F, G, H]
```

| customer_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | G |
| 3 | D |
| 1 | E |
| 2 | H |
| 9 | D |
| 1 | G |
| 9 | H |

I want to extract the following table

| customer_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | E |
| 9 | D |
| 1 | G |
| 9 | H |

I tried with this script but did not succeed.

```
df = df.select("customer_id").distinct().where((F.col("item").isin(list_1)) & (F.col("item").isin(list_2)))
```

```
org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: [UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.LITERAL_TYPE] The feature is not supported: Literal for
```

I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

of course the item cannot be on both of the lists, so the problem you have here is that you are using the `isin` function twice for the lists, and the result is always gonna be empty

now lets say a `customer` bought from `list_1` and `list_2`, now we can use the `isin` function with a one list that contains all the lists we have, and then we can merge the data by `customer_id` and let it count how many items the customer have bought

i used `pyspark.sql`module
[pyspark.sql module](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_set, size

# create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CustomerFilter").getOrCreate()

# define the data
data = [("1", "A"), ("2", "G"), ("3", "D"), ("1", "E"), ("2", "H"), ("9", "D"), ("1", "G"), ("9", "H")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["customer_id", "item"])

# define the lists
list_1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
list_2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"]

# filter the data
df_filtered = df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(collect_set("item").alias("items")) \
    .filter((size(col("items").intersect(list_1)) > 0) & (size(col("items").intersect(list_2)) > 0)) \
    .select("customer_id", "items")

# show the result
df_filtered.show()
```

This customers with `customer_id` 1 and 9, that they have bought items from both list_1 and list_2.

Comment: the empty result is what causes the error you are seeing

Comment: The returned table contains customer_id 2 and 9 which I did not expect. I only want customer_id 1 and 9 because they both bought items from `list_1` and `list_2`. customer_id 2 only bought items from list_2 (G and H)

Comment: oops,the filter  should be an OR condition instead of an AND condition. ill edit it

Comment: Do you have `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable` when you run this script?

Comment: this can happen when we calling a column as a function, you need to use a square bracket, here is a good example: `df.filter(col("age") > 30)()` so we adjust it to be `df.filter(col("age") > 30)` now the `filter()`function should work without popping the `Column`object is not callable" error.

Comment: For some reasons, `df_filtered = df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(collect_set("item").alias("items")) \
    .filter((size(col("items").intersect(list_1)) > 0) & (size(col("items").intersect(list_2)) > 0)) \
    .select("customer_id", "items")` gives me the `Columnobject is not callable error`. I added () to filter `df_filtered = df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(collect_set("item").alias("items")) \
    .filter((size(col("items").intersect(list_1)) > 0) & (size(col("items").intersect(list_2)) > 0))() \
    .select("customer_id", "items")` but did not work

Comment: try debugging each line of your code, also you can try renaming your size variable to something else, or simply restart your kernel to clear any previously defined variables with the same name.

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305443/typeerror-column-object-is-not-callable-using-withcolumn" this would solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252038/discussion-between-michael-and-duc-vu).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track on using `isin` to flag and filter based on the flag. I used a window function to aggregate to get max flag (True if any) value, then filter by both flags are True.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('customer_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = (df.select('*',
                F.col('item').isin(list_1).alias('list_1'),
                F.col('item').isin(list_2).alias('list_2'))
      .select('customer_id', 'item',
              # If there is any True for a customer, take the True value
              F.max('list_1').over(w).alias('list_1'),
              F.max('list_2').over(w).alias('list_2'))
      .filter(F.col('list_1') & F.col('list_2'))
      .select('customer_id', 'item'))
```